# Characteristic Equation, Eigenvalue and Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the characteristic equation, the eigenvalues and bases for the eigenspaces of the matrix.

A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}

I know the value of the characteristic equation is det(A−λI)=0, however, how would I get the eigenvalues from that matrix.
The matrix of A−λI is I believe. I'm not sure where to go from here.
\begin{bmatrix}-λ&-1&0\\-1&-λ&-1\\-1&-1&-λ\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You've made a mistake in calculating $A - \lambda I$. In any case, do you know how to calculate the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix normally?

Comment: As you said, you need the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of $A-\lambda I$ and then set that equal to zero. The eigenvalues will be the solutions for $\lambda$ to that equation.

Comment: Be careful! The identity matrix $I$ is diagonal; it only has non zero elements along its diagonal. Hence when you subtract a scalar multiple of $I$ away from your $A$ it cannot change any of the off diagonal elements! It can only change the elements along the diagonal of $A$.